# Batch For loop writing to text file

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, text

Hello If I run my coding without a loop I get the correct output I am desiring.  Once I add a loop I loose the %temp% in the text file.

**This code works:**

```
CALL tuo "%_ydeck%" "%_enemy%%%k" ordered -v -t %_threads% -o="%~dp0data"\%_member%.txt yf "%_yfort1%,%_yfort2%" climb %_climb%>>temp.txt
for /F "delims=" %%t in ('findstr "Optimized Deck:" temp.txt') do set _temp=%%t
CD Results
ECHO %_member%,%Date%,%_enemy%%%k,%_yfort1% and %_yfort2%,%_temp%>>Raid.txt
CD %~dp0
del temp.txt
```

Once I add the loop I do not get %_temp%.  What do I need to do to fix this.  I have tried SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion with no luck unless I am putting it in the wrong place.

**Here is the code that doesn't work with the loop.**

```
for %%k in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26) do (
CALL tuo "%_ydeck%" "%_enemy%%%k" ordered -v -t %_threads% -o="%~dp0data"\%_member%.txt yf "%_yfort1%,%_yfort2%" climb %_climb%>>temp.txt
for /F "delims=" %%t in ('findstr "Optimized Deck:" temp.txt') do set _temp=%%t
CD Results
ECHO %_member%,%Date%,%_enemy%%%k,%_yfort1% and %_yfort2%,%_temp%>>Raid.txt
CD %~dp0
del temp.txt
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then use `!_temp!` instead of `%_temp%`

Explanation:
In batch when you write `%variable%` it will expand the variable at compile time.
In a case where your variable will change (if you set `_temp` to an other value later), you need to enable delayed expansion. That way you can decide using `!variable!` to expand the variable at run-time instead of compile-time.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.